# 2 dimensional arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to do some C problems I found and this one has me stuck. I have a 10x10 two dimensional array with every element equaling zero. So it looks like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I need to set the top triangle to be `1`s. So it would look like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

How would I do this besides manually doing `arr[0][0] = 1; arr[0][1] = 1; arr[0][2] = 1` and so on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do want you need:

```
n = 10;
for(i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
{
   for(j = i; j < n - i; j++)
      arr[i][j] = 1;
}
```

Comment: It looks right except for some reason the first element of the second row is 1.

Comment: @Petefic It can't be. When i became 1 (and that is at the second row), j starts from 1 (and that is the second column).

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
  for (int col = 0 + row; col < 10 - row; col++) {
    arr[row][col] = 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solution:

```
const int array[10][10] = 
{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
{0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10
#define Type int

Type table[N][N] = { 0 };

void print(Type table[N][N]){
    int x,y;
    for(y = 0; y < N; y++){
        for(x = 0; x < N ; x++){
            printf("%d ", table[y][x]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
} 

int main(){
    int x,y;

    print(table);
    for(y = 0; y < N/2; y++){
        for(x = y; x < N/2;x++){
            table[y][N-x-1]=table[y][x]=1;
        }
    }
    print(table);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you dont mind looping then you can set arr[i][j] = 1 where j >= i and j+i <= 9

Answer (score -1):

```
#define N 10
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        if (i <= j && i < N - j)
            arr[i][j] = 1;
    }
}
```